# List not getting edited, even when mapping in controller

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. I have multiple service classes which are all being mapped into one controller class. It is a sort of 'Note taking' application. Thats the reason there are many models, services, but everything is on one webpage. Right now, I can add a note, delete a note, but edit is not functioning. Before when I had only one dao,model,service,controller, edit used to work. Now i get 404. I am posting the controller and JSP/HTML file. Kindly have a look.None of the edits work, so feel free to choose any one of them. Any, any pointers would be helpful.
Controller class :

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;
    private KeyActivitiesService keyActivitiesService;
    private KernresourcenService kernresourcenService;
    private WertangebotService wertangebotService;
    private KundenhungenService kundenhungenService;
    private KommService kommService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());

        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", new KeyActivities());
        model.addAttribute("kernnotices", new Kernresourcen());

        model.addAttribute("wertnotices", new Wertangebot());
        model.addAttribute("kundNotices", new Kundenhungen());
        model.addAttribute("kommnotices", new KommunikationNotice());

        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        model.addAttribute("listNotices", this.keyActivitiesService.listNotices());
        model.addAttribute("listKernNotices", this.kernresourcenService.listKernNotices());
        model.addAttribute("listWertNotices", this.wertangebotService.listWertNotices());
        model.addAttribute("listKundNotices", this.kundenhungenService.listKundNotices());
        model.addAttribute("listKommNotices", this.kommService.listKommNotices());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){


            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.personService.removePerson(id);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }



    // Here we start with keyactivities controller

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value="keyactivitiesservice")
    public void setKeyActivitiesService(KeyActivitiesService keyActivitiesService){this.keyActivitiesService = keyActivitiesService;}

   // @RequestMapping(value = "/keynotice/listNotices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listKeyNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", new KeyActivities());
        model.addAttribute("listNotices", this.keyActivitiesService.listNotices());
        return "keyactivities";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/keynotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addKeyNotice(@ModelAttribute("keyactivities") KeyActivities p){
        //new person, add it
        this.keyActivitiesService.addKeyNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removenotice/{id}")
    public String removeKeyNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.keyActivitiesService.removeNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editnotice/{id}")
    public String editKeyNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", this.keyActivitiesService.getNoticeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", this.keyActivitiesService.listNotices());
        return "keyactivities";
    }

    //kernesourcen starts


    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "kernresourcenService")
    public void setKernresourcenService(KernresourcenService kernresourcenService){this.kernresourcenService = kernresourcenService;}

   // @RequestMapping(value = "/kernnotice/listKernNotices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listKernNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("kernnotices", new Kernresourcen());
        model.addAttribute("listKernNotices", this.kernresourcenService.listKernNotices());
        return "kernnotices";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/kernnotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addkernNotice(@ModelAttribute("kernnotices") Kernresourcen p){
        //new person, add it
        this.kernresourcenService.addKernNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removekernNotice/{id}")
    public String removeKernNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.kernresourcenService.removeKernNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editkernnotice/{id}")
    public String editKernNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("kernnotices", this.kernresourcenService.getKernNoticenById(id));
        model.addAttribute("kernnotices", this.kernresourcenService.listKernNotices());
        return "kernnotices";
    }

    // Wertangebot controller starts here

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "wertnoticesservice")
    public void setWertangebotService(WertangebotService wertangebotService){this.wertangebotService = wertangebotService;}

  //  @RequestMapping(value = "/wertnotice/listWertNotice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listWertNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("wertnotices", new Wertangebot());
        model.addAttribute("listWertNotices", this.wertangebotService.listWertNotices());
        return "wertnotices";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/wertnotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addWertnotice(@ModelAttribute("wertnotices") Wertangebot p){
        //new person, add it
        this.wertangebotService.addWertNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removewertnotice/{id}")
    public String removeWertNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.wertangebotService.removeWertNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editwertnotice/{id}")
    public String editWertNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("wertnotices", this.wertangebotService.getWertNoticenById(id));
        model.addAttribute("wertnotices", this.wertangebotService.listWertNotices());
        return "wertnotices";
    }

    //Kundenhungen controller starts here

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "kundenhungenService")
    public void setKundenhungenService(KundenhungenService kundenhungenService){this.kundenhungenService=kundenhungenService;}

    //  @RequestMapping(value = "/wertnotice/listWertNotice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listKundNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("kundNotices", new Kundenhungen());
        model.addAttribute("listKundNotices", this.kundenhungenService.listKundNotices());
        return "kundNotices";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/kundnotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addKundnotice(@ModelAttribute("kundNotices") Kundenhungen p){
        //new person, add it
        this.kundenhungenService.addKundNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removekundnotice/{id}")
    public String removeKundNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.kundenhungenService.removeKundNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editkundnotice/{id}")
    public String editKundNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("kundNotices", this.kundenhungenService.getKundNoticeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("kundNotices", this.kundenhungenService.listKundNotices());
        return "kundNotices";
    }


    //Kommunikationsnotice controller starts here.

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "kommService")
    public void setKommService(KommService kommService){this.kommService=kommService;}

    //  @RequestMapping(value = "/wertnotice/listWertNotice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listKommNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("kommnotices", new KommunikationNotice());
        model.addAttribute("listKommNotices", this.kommService.listKommNotices());
        return "kommnotices";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/kommnotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addKommnotice(@ModelAttribute("kommnotices") KommunikationNotice p){
        //new person, add it
        this.kommService.addKommNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removekommnotice/{id}")
    public String removeKommNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){

        this.kommService.removeKommNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editkommnotice/{id}")
    public String editKommNotice(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("kommnotices", this.kommService.getKommNoticeById(id));
        model.addAttribute("kommnotices", this.kommService.listKommNotices());
        return "kommnotices";
    }
}
```

JSP File

```
    <c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="name">
                    <spring:message text="Name"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Partner"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty person.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Partner"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<h3>Partners List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listPersons}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">Partner Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="person">
            <tr>
                <td>${person.name}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${person.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${person.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>

<br>
<c:url var="addAction" value="/keynotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="keyactivities">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="keynotice">
                    <spring:message text="keynotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="keynotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Kernaktivitaten"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Kernaktivitaten"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

<h3>Kernaktivaten List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listNotices}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">Kernaktivaten Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listNotices}" var="keyactivities">
            <tr>
                <td>${keyactivities.keynotice}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editnotice/${keyactivities.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removenotice/${keyactivities.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>


<c:url var="addAction" value="/kernnotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="kernnotices">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty kernnotices.kernresourcenNotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="kernresourcenNotice">
                    <spring:message text="kernresourcenNotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="kernresourcenNotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty kernnotices.kernresourcenNotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Kernnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty person.name}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Kernnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<h3>kernensourcen List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listKernNotices}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">Kernnotice Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listKernNotices}" var="kernnotices">
            <tr>
                <td>${kernnotices.kernresourcenNotice}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editkernnotice/${kernnotices.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removekernNotice/${kernnotices.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>


<c:url var="addAction" value="/wertnotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="wertnotices">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty wertnotices.wertangebotNotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="wertangebotNotice">
                    <spring:message text="wertangebotNotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="wertangebotNotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty wertnotices.wertangebotNotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Wertnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty wertnotices.wertangebotNotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Wertnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<h3>Wertangebot List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listWertNotices}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">Wertnotice Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listWertNotices}" var="wertnotices">
            <tr>
                <td>${wertnotices.wertangebotNotice}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editwertnotice/${wertnotices.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removewertnotice/${wertnotices.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>



<c:url var="addAction" value="/kundnotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="kundNotices">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty kundNotices.kundennotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="kundennotice">
                    <spring:message text="kundennotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="kundennotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty kundNotices.kundennotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Kundennotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty kundNotices.kundennotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Kundennotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<h3>Kundennotices List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listKundNotices}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">kundennotice Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listKundNotices}" var="kundennotices">
            <tr>
                <td>${kundennotices.kundennotice}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editkundnotice/${kundennotices.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removekundnotice/${kundennotices.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>


<c:url var="addAction" value="/kommnotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="kommnotices">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty kommnotices.kommnotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="kommnotice">
                    <spring:message text="kommnotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="kommnotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty kommnotices.kommnotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Kommnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty kommnotices.kommnotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Kommnotice"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<h3>Kommnotices List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listKommNotices}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">Kommnotices Name</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listKommNotices}" var="kommnotices">
            <tr>
                <td>${kommnotices.kommnotice}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editkommnotice/${kommnotices.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removekommnotice/${kommnotices.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

URL links for 404 on edit :

```
http://localhost:8085/mvcmanage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/editnotice/300
http://localhost:8085/mvcmanage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/editkernnotice/200
http://localhost:8085/mvcmanage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/editwertnotice/150
http://localhost:8085/mvcmanage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/editkundnotice/250
http://localhost:8085/mvcmanage-1.0-SNAPSHOT/editkommnotice/200
```

For all the above, I get a 404

New error log : (After clicking on edit for person)

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/person.jsp at line 380

377:         </c:if>
378:         <tr>
379:             <td>
380:                 <form:label path="keynotice">
381:                     <spring:message text="keynotice"/>
382:                 </form:label>
383:             </td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'keyactivities' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f3(person_jsp.java:1969)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f1(person_jsp.java:1740)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.person_jsp._jspService(person_jsp.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
```

Comment: What is the request that results in 404? Which url, method?

Comment: I am adding the URL links of 404 in edit

Comment: When you go to, for example, `.../editnotice/300`, does it enter the controller method `public String editKeyNotice(...)`? Try putting a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Hello, I just checked, it calls the method, and it calls the method from service class also.

Comment: Ok, check if `keyactivities` is resolved to a view (I see you are/were using the same view in `listKeyNotices()`, so you can check if that works). If that is ok, then check all `<jsp:include >`s in it to see if they are mapped properly

Comment: If by resolved to a view means ur asking, if the list method if keyactivities is called, then yes, it is.

Comment: I mean does `keyactivities` resolves to a jsp page, do you have `keyactivities.jsp` in the folder you configured in your `ViewResolver` bean (probably `/WEB-INF`)?

Comment: When I click on edit in ListPersons, I am getting the error I mentioned in my post.. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, there is only one JSP page, on which I am supposed to render all views from different models. That is why I have multiple services, models,dao's, but only one controller as a head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63103/discussion-between-predrag-maric-and-orici).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, these are the most common reasons for getting `404` with Spring MVC:

- Wrong controller mapping (URL or request method)
- View returned from controller method can't be found
- Some of `<jsp:include >` dependencies from the main view can't be found (this goes for the whole include chain)

Check if you have an issue with any of these.